# Using an embedded Iframe in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, iframe, django-models, django-templates

How do I use an Iframe in Django. Currently its searching for the src url in my own files. How do I tell it to not look in my files but to look at the url?

Currently I'm storing the embed code minus the  tag in a database and then trying to dynamically generate it in my template.

```
games.embed = 'allowtransparency="true" width="485" height="402" src="//scratch.mit.edu/projects/embed/82384372/?autostart=false" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen'

{% extends 'code_games/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="game">

      {{games.title|linebreaks}}
      <iframe '{{ games.embed }}'></iframe>

  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The iframe itself shows up on my page but the contents of it don't.

The request URL per the error:

```
Request URL:    http://chacemcguyer.pythonanywhere.com/games/1/%22/scratch.mit.edu/projects/embed/82384372/?autostart=false%22
```

You can see that its searching for the url in my site. How do I get around that?

The error also says:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
```

Then it shows all of my urls from settings.py

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution!

What I had to do was make sure that the iframe content which was coming from my database was `|safe`

I changed:

```
<iframe src='{{ games.embed }}'></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe src='{{ games.embed|safe }}'></iframe>
```